# PHP GET request for cron job - recommendations?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

My site has a function which can accept a number of parameters for displaying images. The way it is currently set up, is when a specific request for images is made (as a GET request to the script with a number of arguments), a MySQL query is made, then the query results are cached in a file so subsequent identical requests don't hit the DB but get the cache file instead (it makes things WAY faster). The cache expires after 8 hours. I wanted to expand on this concept so I created a php script that will make a number of requests to the image script on a scheduler every 8 hours. I am currently using file_get_contents and it does work in my browser, and I intend to run it as a cron job which means it will get called from Unix scheduler. In its most basic form it looks like this:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://www.blabla.com/images.php?action=getpics&imagetype=recent& per_page=60&page=1&orderby_view=0&tag_filter=trees');
```

It does work but is there a better or more elegant/safe way to do this? Eventually I will loop the arguments so multiple GETs are made so the most general searches get cached.

Comment: Wouldn't increasing cache time be much easier then any this trickery?

Comment: only a small and not very usefull side note so sorry about that, but.. it's called CRON job, not a chron job. But as suggested by Alexei here, increasing cache time seems to be so much better solution. And if you need to invalidate the cache for some reason, you can adopt a concept, where you send and extra GET parameter with an ever growing value everytime you need to invalidate the cache

Comment: my basic problem is that I don't want users to ever hit an uncached response. Since our image search is so simple there are a limited number of parameters that can be used so I wanted the cron job to get everything cached before any live user made a request and possibly had a long time to get the results.